# blender not rendering smoke animation unless I pre-bake?

Tags: fire

Hoping you can help. Have a peculiar situation here.

I've included the blend file here.

Simple set up. I have a cube as the domain for the smoke, then a mesh object as the flow for the smoke, and an emission shader. I am using blender 2.79.

If I try and render this animation (i.e., press F12 after opening the file to render the first frame) - I get nothing but "black" (not rendered).

BUT - if I click on "bake all dynamics" in the cube (or even just one frame) - then all of the sudden it magically works. I can either press F12 on ANY frame (and it renders it properly) - OR - animate in the timeline and it figures it out.

I don't want to have to 'bake' before I render. I just want to open the file, then render, without having to pre-bake.

How do I fix this?

Thanks very much for your help!

Here is the blend file:
[image]

Comment: the thing is, the smoke baking is mandatory, as the manual says (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/introduction.html#workflow). Running the animation bakes each frame as well...

Comment: is there any way around the smoke baking? or a different way of donig this to achieve the same effect?

Comment: OR - is there a way I can bake "into" the saved blend file, so when I re-open it - I don't have to 're-bake'?

Comment: well, when you bake the smoke sim, blender saves it in a subfolder, respect to the file folder, named like "blendcache_xxxx", where xxxx is the name of the file. If you quit blender , then reopen the same xxxx file, the simulation will be loaded from the saved cache, and you can just move to a frame and render, no need to re-bake it again (if the file is untouched)

Comment: hmm, seems like a good idea - but all I have are ".bphys" files (no blender files), and clicking on any of those in the cache folder do not seem to open up in blender... any other ideas?

Comment: no you open the blend file, and those saved bakes there are just working... maybe experiment with a simple example (cube with "quick smoke" applied)

Comment: kk, finally figured it out, thx. I didn't realize you actually do have to pre-bake these physics, I thought they would be rendered at run time, and baking was optional (to speed things up).